# Model Binding an interface in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have seen this blog post about how you can now create a model binder provider to support interfaces.

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/08/16/An-inheritance-aware-ModelBinderProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx

However I am at a loss as how to handle the actual Model Binder.

I know I can inherit the `DefaultModelBinder` but how do I then work out the relevant concrete class in the custom model binder, do you do this in the CreateModel function? and if so how do you do it?

Example structure for my interface and some of the classes:

```
public interface IAnswerControlViewModel : IQuestionAnswerControl
{
...
}

public class AnswerControl<T> : IAnswerControlViewModel
{
..
}

public class AnswerCheckBox : AnswerControl<bool>
{

}

public class AnswerMultiLineText : AnswerControl<string>
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public override string Value { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerCheckBoxListModal: AnswerControl<AnswerMultiSelectListValueType>
{
    public string ModalName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model binding I have got in my Global.asax using the example from the blog post:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IAnswerControlViewModel), new AnswerControlModelBinder());

var answerControlBinderProvider = new InheritanceAwareModelBinderProvider
{
    { typeof (IAnswerControlViewModel), new AnswerControlModelBinder() }
};
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(answerControlBinderProvider);
```

The goal is to have MVC know how to model bind to this during a post to an action:

```
public IList<IAnswerControlViewModel> AnswerControls { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your problems right, your solution might be the usage of a Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control framework like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), but [there](http://unity.codeplex.com/) [are](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) [many](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) [others](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison). Depending of the framework, you can configure the mappings from Interface to concrete class.

Then all you have to do is resolve the concrete class with commands like:

```
var concrete = IoCContainer.Resolve<IAnswerControlViewModel>();
```

or if the type is stored in a variable:

```
var concrete = IoCContainer.Resolve(ModelBindingContext.ModelType);
```

And everything works automagically.

Comment: I am using Ninject already but I don't know how to apply this to the model binding. My situation seems a bit more complicated than your example, because I have a generic AnswerControl<T> class which uses that interface but also other classes that inherit from AnswerControl<T> that are expected to be in the same AnswerControls list.

Comment: So far I have found this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx which has an example abstract model binder which explains a bit more about handling my situation but I haven't come up with a solution yet.

Comment: At some point you will have to configure/tell the model binder (or the IoC container) which model to bind, I don't think that it can "guess" which one is the right, since you might have multiple identical concrete implementations etc. Maybe you want to have a hardcoded or configured Dictionary, describing the type to map back? Might make your live much easier. Just things to think about :)